# PHP SimplePie throwing unserialize error on Feeds::make($feedUrl, 100)

Tags: php, laravel, simplepie

When using SimplePie to get a list of the latest rss posts, the following code sometimes throws errors:

```
$rssPosts = Feeds::make($rssFeedUrl, 100);

PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 1177620 of 1179648 bytes in /mypath/vendor/simplepie/simplepie/library/SimplePie/Cache/File.php on line 126
```

This only happens for certain feeds, sometimes. Can someone help me to understand what would be done to handle this scenario properly, and still get RSS posts? Seems like the feed is corrupted in some way.

Can be reproduced using the following feed:

```
$rssFeedUrl = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Makeuseof";
$rssPosts = Feeds::make($rssFeedUrl, 100);
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution or how did you solve it please?